# Force Trigger Refresh

Tags: reactjs, grafana, refresh

trying to force trigger a refresh in my React plugin code so that when I press a button a refresh occurs and therefore updates the grafana widgets.

The current implementation that I have tried is using location service.

```
    locationService.partial({});
```

I can confirm that my button listener is working correctly, but this specific code doesnt seem to do anything.

How can I trigger a refresh that would affect the entire dashboard and all panels?